# Stanford Maxenttagger vs. Stanford Parser

Tags: stanford-nlp

I have several questions .

1. What is the difference between Maxenttagger and "normal" Stanford Parser?
2. Why is the Maxenttagger so much faster than the parser? In my project, the parser needs 30 seconds and the Maxenttagger needs 5 seconds.
3. Why both provide different results? It is possible to adjust the Maxenttagger so that it provides the same results as the parser? Or is the speed then how the parser?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer to all the of your questions is the same: the parser and tagger are completely separate algorithms. The parser is a CKY parser, which happens to produce POS tags while parsing. The tagger is a sequence model built only for POS tagging. The tagger is therefore faster, but doesn't produce parse trees. As for why they have different outputs: they make different mistakes on account of being different algorithms.